# Pointing struct's pointer member

Tags: c, pointers, struct, 8051

I am getting an error from my compiler as follow:

> C51 COMPILER V9.01 - SN: C1ADC-HAI60D COPYRIGHT KEIL ELEKTRONIK GmbH
>   1987 - 2009
>   *** WARNING C260 IN LINE 300 OF SEQUENCE.C: '=': pointer truncation
>   *** ERROR C190 IN LINE 301 OF SEQUENCE.C: '&': not an lvalue

The following is my code:

```
   struct myCond{
    unsigned char currStatus;
    unsigned char prevStatus;
    unsigned int *timer;
    unsigned char *flag;
   }
  struct myCond StatCond;

  unsigned int data timerdata;
  bit bdata timeflag;

  void someSubroutine (void)
  {
    struct myCond *tempCond;

tempCond = &StatCond;
tempCond->timer = &((unsigned int)timerdata);
tempCond->flag = &((unsigned char)timeflag);
  }
```

Comment: You forgot a `;` after your struct declaration. I don't think it's the only point to correct though, your type declarations are quite strange.

Comment: Which of these lines is line 300? Which is 301?

Answer (score 3):

Are we supposed to guess which line is 301?

The problems, as I understand are here:

```
tempCond->timer = &((unsigned int)timerdata);
tempCond->flag = &((unsigned char)timeflag);
```

`(unsigned int)timerdata` and `(unsigned char)timeflag` are values, `r-values` to be precise. They cannot be modified or assigned unlike `l-values`, which plain `timerdata` and `timeflag` are. And so you can't take addresses of `r-values` with `&`. It would be the same as, say, writing `&1`. `1` on its own does not exist as an object in data memory.

You should write instead:

```
tempCond->timer = &timerdata;
tempCond->flag = (unsigned char*)&timeflag;
```

And I'm not quite sure that it is legal to take an address of a bit variable. The last line may fail to compile.

Perhaps redefining the structure would help:

```
struct myCond{
...
    bit bdata *flag; // or maybe without bdata
   }
```

and then you'd write `tempCond->flag = &timeflag;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int data timerdata;  // what is 'data', is it defined?
bit bdata timerflag;  // what are 'bit' and 'bdata', are they defined?
```

Check your code with regard to my questions above.  Compiler errors are often reported multiple lines after the real offense.

Comment: The `bdata` and `data` datatypes are defined by the Keil : [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_bdata.htm)